# class DBNull{} showing in report when I filter out NULLs

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and writing a report that should filter out all records that have NULL in column X.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE T
WHERE T.OWNER IS NOT NULL
```

Result:

```
ID        OWNER  
--------------------------      
1         JACK
2         TOM
3         class DBNull {}
7         SUE
```

"class DBNull{}" is new to me.  I would like all records with "class BDNull {}" value to be filtered out as well.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community.  Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. It is difficult to answer questions without know what you are using nor the code behind it. BTW what is "class DBNull{}",one thing it is not: Postgres.

Comment: @Belayer Thanks for the suggestions.  I made changes to the question, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: Looks like a completely broken database design, seems like you stored the literal string "class DBNull {}" into the table.

Comment: @Alejandro I am not new to SQL, but am new to PostgreSQL and this database.  The reports I created show "class DBNull {}" value for several fields when they are supposed show nothing, but not always.  For some records those fields do show nothing the way I would expect them to, but for others they show up with "class DBNull {}" value.  I did some reading on class DBNull {} but still don't understand why this value would shop up in the field.

Comment: @Komsinica That suggest that a faulty client is inserting that literal string into the DB. You should try to locate it and clean up the already broken records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So "class DBNull{}" is just the value within the owner column and you wish to exclude. Then just extend your where clause with *and t.owner not like "class DBNull%*. ( I use "not like" so as to catch either value represented "class BDNull{}" and "class DBNull { }".

```
select * 
  from table t
 where t.owner is not null
   and t.owner is not like 'class DBNull%';
```

This is pretty **basic SQL**. I suggest you spend some time with a good textbook or SQL tutorial.

Comment: Thank you.  I am quite familiar with like and not like operators, just didn't occur to me to use them.  I was using = operator which did not work on `t.owner = 'class DBNull {}'`